# Reading xml file created with Chilkat

Tags: xml, zip, xmldocument, chilkat

What I have: Xml file created with `ChilkatDotNet4`'s `Xml` class, some node in that file with binary content (data in code below is byte array). zipFlag that is passed to `SetBinaryContent` show that content would be zipped. How file is being created:

```
var zipFlag = true;
var ecryptFlag = false;
var password = string.empty;

var xml = new Xml();
var node = xmlFile.FindChild("SomeNode");
node.SetBinaryContent(data, zipFlag, ecryptFlag, password); //in file it is base64 text
```

What I need: to read this file with `System.Xml.XmlDocument`, and get the binary content from the "SomeNode" node.

What I've tried: read innerText of "SomeNode", get byte array with `FromBase64String`, and then unzip with `GZipStream`, but got `InvalidDataException` *(The magic number in GZip header is not correct. Make sure you are passing in a GZip stream)*

I strongly believe that someone has already faced the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The binary data is the output of the deflate algorithm (no GZip structure enclosing it).   I suspect System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream will do it.